# Recursion not getting me the output I need

Tags: c, recursion

I'm new to programing and I'm doing recursion exercises, and one of them was to count how many odd numbers I have inside a number:

this is my code:

```
int countOdd(int num, int count)
{
    int temp;
    printf("num\n%d", num);
    if (num<ZERO)return count;
    temp = num % 10;
    if ((temp % 2) != 0) countOdd(num / 10, count + ONE);
    printf("test");
    countOdd(num / 10, count);


}
```

its suppose to get the number and count how many odd number there is and return it as a value, could someone explain to me why it isn't working, tips and ideas will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using `ZERO` instead of 0, and `ONE` instead if 1? You have to do the recursion for every digit, and do `count + 1` only if the current digit is odd. Also your end condition should be `num == 0`, there is no way that a positive integer divided by 10 is going to be negative.

Answer (score 4):

whatever non-negative value divided by 10 will be again non-negative.

But your recursion termination condition is `if (num<ZERO)return count;`, that will never happen.

A fixed variant of your code may look like this (still using recursion for your educational reasons, otherwise non recursive code would be better):

```
int countOdd(int num) {
    if (num <= 0) return 0;
    return (num&1) + countOdd(num/10);
}
```

Also don't use `printf` for debugging your code, use proper debugger.

Comment: Great answer. Yet, I'd put the second `return` in an `else` clause because it's a symmetrical situation.

Comment: @meaning-matters hmm.. you mean `else` to the previous `return 0;` path? I can understand that, but I prefer my way, in more complex source the early `if (..) return early something;` without `else { }` avoid excessive indentation. It makes reading code flow a bit harder as multiple exit paths exist in single function, but in case of the simple terminal conditions from my experience it is easier to read+maintain multi-return brevity code with limited blocks, than single return path with lot of nested blocks.

Comment: `return (num != 0) ? countOdd(num / 10, count + (num & 1)) : count;`

Comment: @nemequ I don't have two arguments input on `countOdd`... feel free to post your own answer with own variant of course, this comment is just question what you  mean, as I can't see how that relates to my example. (even if I would use the excessive second `count` argument, your code basically doesn't bring any significant advantage, as it will assemble into roughly same machine code).

Comment: I mean, the two argument design is wrong, as it is clearly not needed in this case, and every additional argument on recursion means bigger stack memory usage per calling depth (not that it matters in this case, as `int` can have only 10 digits at most, so this is like tickling the stack on surface), but IMO the OP function signature design is worse than my (worse by a "league", not just cosmetically).

Comment: what is that? (num&1) bitwise operator? @Ped7g

Comment: @AlexAlex integer numbers in computers are usually stored in binary encoding, in the "bits". An `int` type in C on most of the current common target platforms is 32 bits "wide". If you will check how values are encoded in binary, you will see that the lowest bit is set to 1 iff the value is odd. And when value is odd, it's last digit is odd (in base 10 "human" formatting). So I use the lowest bit value to add count of odd digits at last position (either one or zero), then by doing `/10` I remove that digit and continue recursively with shortened value to count odd digits on remaining positions

Comment: is there a way to do that without this operand? &1 because I'm not allowed to use that to solve this problem (school)

Comment: @alex In this case the `(num&1)` part could be written as `(num % 2)`

Comment: is there a way? Yes, there're are millions of ways. You are doing `temp % 2` which any sane compiler will assemble as `temp&1` anyway, so you are actually using it too, you just don't see it, nor you don't demonstrate that you understand binary numbers and CPU performance characteristics. Forcing you to write odd-ness test by `% 2` even when you understand what `& 1` does is cruel joke, and I would object with lector. Keep in mind that every time somebody writes `x % 2` in C source, a kitten dies, which is very cruel and irresponsible. (the exact replacement is `(x&1)` <=> `(x % 2)`  (fixed)

Comment: Haha I'm very sorry but I'm a beginner and this what the teacher demands, I actually do understand the bit wise a bit and I do understand your point, I promise when I will write my own code I will use it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you're supposed to return something. So make sure you return something, i.e., add the missing return statements. Also terminate the recursion when you reach zero, or you'll have an infinite loop.

```
int countOdd(int num, int count)
{
    int temp;
    printf("num\n%d", num);
    if (num<=ZERO) return count;
    temp = num % 10;
    if ((temp % 2) != 0) return countOdd(num / 10, count + ONE);
    printf("test");
    return countOdd(num / 10, count);
}
```

Comment: Nice catch with the missing returns, I actually completely overlooked it. IMO it's very good OP can now see also fixed code which looks almost identical to his original one, as my variant is (intentionally) completely different almost in every aspect.